# Rails -- Possible to run migration methods in generic rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rake

I know this is not best practice, and most likely shouldn't even be used, as thats what migrations are used for, but I was wondering if its possible to execute migration specific commands in a regular rake task. Something like:

```
namespace :dummy do
    task :update => :environment do
      add_column :users, :deleted, :boolean, { :null => false, :default => false }
   end
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to run arbitrary pseudo-migrations in your rake tasks:

```
namespace :dummy do
  task :update => :environment do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.add_column :users, :deleted, :boolean, :null => false, :default => false
  end
end
```

If you're doing a lot of that sort of thing, use short-hand:

```
namespace :dummy do
  task :update => :environment do
    c = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

    c.add_column :users, :deleted, :boolean, :null => false, :default => false
  end
end
```

Comment: Good to know. I didn't realize that those functions were a part of the connection class.

Thanks.

Comment: There's a lot of good stuff in there if you look around. I'm a big fan of the connection object, especially things like select_values.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should do something like this:

```
namespace :dummy do
  task :update => :enviroment do
    ActiveRecord::Migration.send(:add_column, :users, :deleted, :boolean, { :null => false, :default => false })
  end
end
```

Not tested, but the important thing here is to include the migration class and then send the method you wish to run.

**UPDATED** to use `ActiveRecord::Migration` directly via @tadman

Comment: Including an arbitrary migration seems odd. Why not just bang against ActiveRecord::Migration directly?

Comment: For some reason, I was under the assumption that if I used the ActiveRecord::Migration class directly, it would attempt to insert a record in the schema_migrations table

Comment: I believe the only way you can trigger an addition to the schema_migrations table is to define an ActiveRecord::Migration.up method and run it.